# How can I make a regex that allows the $(dollar sign) in the first position?

Tags: wpf, regex, validation, xaml, currency

I am using a ValueConverter to display `double` types as currency. I want to make sure the entry is valid, so I tried using this validation method I made up. My only problem seems to be that I can't select the whole value (ie $500.00) and type anything. If the '$' is not selected, everything seems fine. How can I fix this?

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MoneyConverter}, Path=fr}"
  PreviewTextInput="ValidateMoney" DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ValidateMoney(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(\$)[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$|^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
  e.Handled = !rgx.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text));
}
public class MoneyConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    if (value != null) {
      double d;
      string temp = value.ToString();
      if (double.TryParse(temp, out d)) {
        return String.Format("{0:C}", d);
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    if (value != null) {
      double d;
      string temp = value.ToString();
      if (double.TryParse(temp, out d)) {
        return String.Format("{0:C}", d);
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to including the dollar sign is correct, though the parentheses are unnecessary. It is sufficient to write this: `^\$`.

You can simplify your regular expression a lot:

- You don't need three separate cases in your alternation. There is some unnecessary repetition there.
- `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`.
- You probably want to ensure that there is at least one digit.

Try this:

```
@"^\$?(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$"
```

Or using capturing groups to reduce clutter:

```
@"^\$?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$"
```

Some other points:

- You should be aware that `TryParse` is affected by the current culture. `1.990` means different things depending on your culture.
- `ToString` also depends on culture. The `"{0:C}"` format doesn't guarantee a dollar sign.
- Your regular expression allows things like `$.990`. That might be what you want, but it looks a little odd to me.
- You should probably use `decimal` rather than `double` to store monetary amounts. The `double` type can't store `1.99` exactly, but `decimal` can.
- I replaced `[.]` with the equivalent `\.` but that is just a matter of taste. Both do the same thing.

Comment: (I ask this question out of ignorance) Why bother specifying that your groups are non-capturing groups? In this case the user isn't capturing *anything*, so it seems like the `?:` just add visual cutter to the regex. Is there a performance benefit by specifying non-capturing?

Comment: @ean5533: Yes there is a performance benefit but it is minor. It's not essential to use non-capturing groups. I can post another version without them.

Comment: @ean5533: The performance difference might become relevant if the (non-)capturing group is used in heavily backtracked parts of the regex. It gets also annoying when you have many subpatterns, but only need the backreferences of a few of those. I guess, these two reasons explain why it is generally considered better practice to make all groups non-capturing when possible. @MarkByers, I wouldn't say that changing `[.]` to `\.` is a simplification. Both are absolutely valid methods to escape a character, and with some characters (especially brackets), I think the `[]` is more readable.

Comment: @m.buettner: You could be right that the OP thinks `[.]` is more readable than `\.`, in which case he is most welcome to undo this change. However judging by the general quality of the rest of the expression I suspect that he simply was not aware that it was possible to write `\.`. Now at least he can make an informed choice between both options based on his personal preference.

Comment: @MarkByers yup fair enough. Your answer just made it sound like `\.` is somehow better than `[.]`, while I would think it's mostly a matter of taste

Comment: @m.buettner: Agreed. I've reworded my answer. Please let me know if you have other concerns.

Comment: i replaced my regex with yours, and I now can't type the '.' either.  But mostly, the question is still unanswered:  How to fix the problem where when the entire value is highlighted, no entry is allowed.  What improvments are you suggesting I make to ToString and TryParse?  How can i eliminate the input of ie .990

Comment: so what would you do with TryParse and ToString?